# How to keep X most recent git reflog entries indefinitely

Tags: git

Sometimes I work on a project, then leave it for a long time before coming back to it.
`git reflog` will automatically delete entries that are older than 90 days, so if I return to my project after this length of time then `git reflog` will be empty, which could be inconvenient.

I could set the expiration time to longer than 90 days, but what if I return to a project after an even longer time?  I could tell `git reflog` never to delete entries - but I don't want to be storing hundreds of years-old `reflog` entries!

What I would like is to keep the last X entries indefinitely.  For example, if X = 10, I would like to be able to come back to my project after a long break, and there are still 10 entries in the `reflog`, but all the older ones have been deleted.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Reflogs are (mostly—`git stash` abuses its reflog, but Git has a built in exception for this reflog anyway) for *error recovery in an active repository*, not for discovering commits. That is, say you run `git rebase` and two days later you realize the whole idea of rebasing was wrong: the reflog can help you "un-rebase". It's not meant for long term usage.

Answer (score 1):

You may be mentally assigning the reflog too much power. It's just a list of commits. The important thing is the SHA of each commit. If you think now that a certain commit might be important to you later (to reset to, perhaps), just write down its SHA. Example:

```
badfeed1 - This was the head just before I rebased myBranch
```

Of course, that doesn't guarantee that the commit in question will *exist* later. So even better would be to assign that commit a branch or tag name. That will keep it alive forever. If your tag name expresses why the commit is potentially important to you (like my note above), the problem is completely solved.

Of course, you may also be misunderstanding what the reflog *is*. It's effectively just a text file; it's no bigger than the list. So if there were a way to make all entries stick around forever, it wouldn't do any harm memory-wise (though of course, as I just said, most of the commits referred to may well have ceased to exist).

But I would also have to wonder why the reflog is so important to you. All *existing* commits are available through the *real* log (`git log`). The reflog is generally useful only if you've made a drastic mistake (like a rebase that proved mistaken, as in my example above). And that is the sort of thing you're likely to want to fix within the next five seconds, not after the passage of 90 days.

Thus it seems likely that you're misusing `git reflog`. If the idea is simply to have a form of log that takes up less space, the usual thing is to say

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```

This is *so* common to say, in fact, that most serious users have a Git alias for it (mine is `git lll`).

Comment: If a commit hash ID is listed in a reflog entry, that commit is protected from the Grim Collector. (Or, well, is *supposed* to be: the same goes for `HEAD` entries, and for blobs in an index, but between Git 2.5 and 2.15, `git worktree add`-ed working trees failed to get scanned, so there's always potential for bugs here. :-) )

Comment: Although I'm not going to accept this answer because it doesn't directly answer the question, I think it is what I was looking for.  

I typically use ```git reflog``` instead of ```git log```, since the output takes up less space (I suppose I should use ```--oneline```).

Comment: Added how you should be using `git log` to my answer.